# Which is the best Library to use access a Database using SQL from Scala?

Tags: sql, database, scala, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am looking for a Scala Database library which allows me to use SQL to talk to Databases with Connection pooling and preferably multiple end points (master and slave) taken care of.

The Scala ORM/DSL tools look too complicated and have a higher learning curve without much value addition for my use case. So I am looking for a simpler library which allows me write SQL directly.

But the connection pooling is a must for the library.

Any suggestions for the above?.

Comment: Not sure if this is the complicated ORM you refer to but http://circumflex.ru/projects/orm/index.html looks pretty close to SQL.

Comment: [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/) is nice too, if you're looking for lightweight tool.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple endpoints?

Comment: In what environment is this supposed to run? Connection pooling is typically done by some piece of infrastructure, i.e. an application server.

Comment: If you just want to do SQL you can use straight JDBC.

Comment: @JensSchauder Plan to run as a standalone app / or in a Web App Server - Tomcat.

Comment: Your point that you don't want to learn a DSL is a valid one, but you shouldn't underestimate the benefits of having your queries type-checked for you. Once you've experienced that, there is no going back to strings...

Comment: Don't forget to do JDBC connection pooling http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JDBC in scala is pretty much seamless. In my case, I wrote a small reusable db library for bridging JDBC to Scala (i.e., generate SQL from Scala objects and generate scala objects from results).

For pooling, you could use a 3rd party db pool library (such as http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/)
Using all this in Scala (once your library is done) requires very few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer SQueryL as it has semantics like Scala Collections but accesses the database, this means that operations which usually use Scala collections can work more easily with its abstractions. http://squeryl.org/

Answer (score 1):

Doesn'T ScalaQuery work for you? http://scalaquery.org/

Comment: ScalaQuery requires me to learn a DSL. I believe SQL is the best DSL out there.

Comment: Ok then you should go with JDBC

Comment: No, it doesn't require a DSL. Both ScalaQuery and its successor Slick support plain SQL queries with a nice Scala-like abstraction over JDBC.

Comment: @sheki a DSL is just a API, personally I like .NET LINQ the most when working with Database or other Collction resources. SLICK scalaquerys successor intends to offer that for scala, but it has a long, long way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer SQL over ORM you definitely should check [O/R Broker](http://code.google.com/p/orbroker/) JDBC library. Unfortunately I'm not sure if it supports connection pooling or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the most popular nowadays is [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/), and you should check if that is up-to-date with google trends: https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=slick%20scala%2C%20scalikejdbc%2C%20Anorm&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-2